# Removing semicolon to installed PHP extensions is not working

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

So I update my php version to latest(8.0.12), and now I try to get in MySQL using XAMPP, it showing

```
Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require the following PHP extensions to be installed: mysqli, openssl
```

I already remove the starting semicolon in php.ini, look like this

```
extension=mysqli
extension=openssl
```

but just not working and I just don't know why, please help.

Comment: Did you restart Apache after changes the php.ini?

Comment: If you are on a Linux then also did you install these extensions from your repo

Comment: @Lessmore I did, even restart the pc.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm on PC

Comment: Does XAMPP have a seperate `php.ini` file to be used by the PHP CLI from the one used by PHP in Apache

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't think so? I only saw one php.ini file in C:\xampp